# jQuery reset validation on a form in a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling to reset a form within a dialog window upon close. My form is using jQuery validate and I've tried to use the documented resetForm() function, but no luck.

Below are two attempts on how I am trying to achieve clearing the form upon the user hitting "Close". Neither are working.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjT7T/6/

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // Attempt to reset the form using JQuery validates resetForm(), not working.
        var validator = $("#myForm").validate();
        validator.resetForm();
        // Attempt to reset the form and remove the error classes, not working either. 
        $(this).closest("form")[0].reset().removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? `$(this).closest("form")[0].reset().removeClass("error");` the javascript function `reset()` does not return a jQuery object, try it without `.removeClass`

Comment: removing the removeClass() worked. thanks.. but I cannot seem to get it to remove the class. The odd thing is, as I inspect it in Firebug, it actually removes the class properly, but when I click the dialog again, the class "error" returns :(

Comment: Can you post your code at jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried plain javascript reset?

```
document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
```

Or even jQuery, but with the form's id:

```
$("#myForm").reset();
```

And to remove the class, why note use the `#id`

```
$("#myForm").removeClass("error");
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, unfortunately the removeClass is not working within the dialog. The behavior I get when viewing in Firebug is such that the class appears to be removed upon close. However, when I re-open the dialog "Error" returns. It's very odd.

Comment: I would just like to remove all instances of the class "red" in that example when the user closes the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I actually think the jQuery validate plugin is doing something funky. Your example works, but still not working in my implementation. The validate plugin is controlling if the initial class is added.. hmm.

Comment: Does your implementation have other form elements than inputs, e.g. selects and textareas?

Comment: Perhaps, you can paste a sample of your original code in a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually just went ahead and put a clear on my open within the dialog and it works. I feel like I shouldn't have to do that, but whatever.

Comment: Thanks again Patrick, related question - Any idea how to traverse to the form from within a dialog close: event? $(this).closest("form"); is not working.

Comment: No problem. I need to know the ID of the form within the dialog from within my "close:".

Comment: Ok, on the jsfiddle, the form is a child of #myDialog so instead of using `$(this).closest("form")` you'd have to use `$(this).children("form")`.